# How to disable admin bar in wordpress 3.9?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to disable admin bar for registered users, whiche are not administrators. I found many solutions like adding

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'add_users' ) ) {
show_admin_bar( false ); }
```

to functions.php, but it totally doesn't work. As I understand it is problem of "the best" version 3.9. I also tried many plugins - there are no working ones... Does any solution exist today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the filter? Add this to your functions.php replacing your existing code:

```
function wpse_hide_admin_bar() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_settings' ) ) {
        return true; // Show for admins
    } else {
        return false; // Hide for other users
    }
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'wpse_hide_admin_bar' );
```

Comment: doesn't work :( user with role contributor still can see admin bar

Comment: Please retry. I have made a slight modification to make it admin specific

Comment: oops, i disabled all plugins and it started working... i'm going to find bad bro. thank you very much! 7 minutes to accept answer :)

Comment: it is "Maintenance" plugin, if it's interesting.. it is not bug, but his option

Answer (score 1):

including this line of code in functions.php will disable it altogether,

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Edit: The accepted answer is better than my answer, because that method doesn't disable the admin bar altogether, but it disables it based on the user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Users > Admin Profile > Toolbar > Deselect "Show Toolbar when viewing site"